# jQuery mobile loading page inside static div

Tags: jquery-mobile, single-page-application

[image: Eg image for referal]Is it possible to load jQuery mobile page into a static div container ?
I have a requirement where the whole frame remains the same but inside part of view has to change according to the clicks [image: for eg. consider this image]

I have refered this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205400/load-page-to-a-div-jquery-mobile) but it did not help.

Comment: you main load pages inside a different _pageContainer_?

Comment: Are you using a single or multi-part app. this would vary the answer. I just did something similar to this using the native navbars to create a fixed header and footer.